# Why is a red border shown by default in a form?

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML:

```
  <form ng-submit="submitForm()"  method="POST">
    <div class="formRow"><input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="form.emailId"  name="email" required></div>
    <button type="submit" ngclick="Submit">Signin</button>
```

It is showing a red border by default. Why?

When I inspect the HTML in Firefox I see this:

```
<input type="email" required="" name="email" ng-model="form.emailId" placeholder="Email" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-email">
```

Any idea?

Comment: Something's obviously altering the output within the JS maybe?

Comment: A suspect its claiming the form input isn't valid. does this happen just on page load? do you have any code that's firing the validate on the firm?

Comment: it is happening on page load.

Comment: You have several `class` attributes there that could have been styled by some css code. Check freefaller's opinion

Comment: there is no such class

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443487/angular-automatically-add-ng-invalid-class-on-required-fields

Answer (score 1):

That could be that this is browser highlighting. In HTML5 we have form input validation, and your input has type `email`. That is why if the content does not match `email` field requirements there could appear red border.

To prevent this set `novalidate` attribute to the form.

```
<form novalidate action="/some/action" method="POST"></form>
```

Hope that helps somehow.

[novalidate](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) on W3C.

Comment: what about validation ??

Comment: empty validation will go away in this case

Comment: It won't go away, it will still be validated but no browser specific action will take place. I mean no specific decoration.

Comment: i am not able to see message or red border after that. if i submit blank form

Comment: In a controller you can check if form is valid or not: add name to you form, f.e `LoginForm`, then in submit method check: `if ($scope.LoginForm.$invalid) { return null; }`... or something like that...

Comment: By the way what version of Angular you're using?